# 'Access Denied' when trying to connect to Amazon-RDS instance using SSL from shared hosting (but it works when testing locally)

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, ssl, mysqli, amazon-rds

I'm trying to deploy a web app to a shared hosting provider (Strato), but I have problems establishing a SSL-connection to the Amazon-RDS instance that I'm using.
While testing the web app locally (using XAMPP) it works fine, but on the shared hosting I get a HTTP-500 error response after a 2 minute timeout.

My web app is using the Code Igniter framework (but I think this is not what's causing the issue). The database user was created using the REQUIRE SSL attribute to enforce the use of SSL. The user's "host" value is "%" to allow for remote connections.

At first I checked the apache error logs. They said

```
"19.09.2019 10:13:23 my-url.de [client XXXX:XXXX:XXXX::] End of script output before headers: index.php"
```

everytime I tried to access the site.
Then I tried to test a minimal example not even using Code Igniter (code below).

```php
$servername = "XXXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXXXX.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "db_name";

$con = mysqli_init();
if (!$con){
    die("mysqli_init failed");
}

$ca_filename = realpath('./../cert/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem');
echo 'Does the ca file exist? '. (file_exists($ca_filename) ? 'true' : 'false').'<br>';

$con->options(MYSQLI_OPT_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT, FALSE);
mysqli_ssl_set(
    $con,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    realpath('./../cert/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem'),
    NULL,
    NULL); 

if (!mysqli_real_connect($con,$servername, $username, $password, $dbname, 3306))
{
    die("Connect Error: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

echo "Connected to database.<br>";

$res = $con->query("SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Ssl_cipher'");
$row = $res->fetch_assoc();
if(empty($row['Value'])) {
    echo 'No SSL';
} else {
    echo $row['Value'].'<br>';
}

mysqli_close($con);
```

I would expect some output like

```
Does the ca file exist? true
Connected to database.
DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
```

When testing it locally (using XAMPP) I got the following output:

```
Does the ca file exist? true
Connected to database.
DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
```

<s>(this is weird because it says "No SSL" even though the user requires SSL - but the connection is established)</s>
EDIT: This looks like it's working correctly.

Then I was testing it on the shared hosting and got this as an output:

```
Does the ca file exist? true
Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'username'@'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX' (using password: YES) in /shared/hosting/path/htdocs/public/dbtest.php on line 25 Connect Error: Access denied for user 'username'@'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX' (using password: YES)
```

**UPDATE 1**

By comparing the `phpinfo()` of my local server with the one of the shared hosting I found out that my local server uses "mysqlnd" (MySQL Native Driver) while the shared hosting server uses "mysql". The info in "mysqlnd" says "core SSL: supported" while there's absolutely no SQL-related info on SSL in the `phpinfo()` of the shared hoster. Is it impossible to establish a SSL connection without mysqlnd?

**UPDATE 2**

I did another run using PDO instead of mysqli. Same problem: Works locally, but not on shared hosting. This time I got the error message `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined class constant 'MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT'`. I read [here](https://www.kamenov.biz/php-application-cannot-connect-to-mysql-over-ssl/) that if this happens it means I need to upgrade the PHP version (which is weird because the hosting server is running PHP 7.2.22). Even after changing the PHP version to 7.3.9 (which is newer than the one I use locally), the error still occurs. If I delete the line `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT => FALSE` from the new script version, I get the `Access denied` error again.

Comment: the password is incorrect your RDS is reacable `using password: YES`, double check the password.

Comment: @Adiii I'm using the exact same file locally and on the shared hosting. No differences at all (including the password). I also just double checked it now.

Comment: is the version same on local and shared hosting?

Comment: @Adiii You mean PHP version? Local version is 7.3.7, shared hosting version is 7.2.22. Is it possible that this causes the issue?
EDIT: Just changed the shared hosting PHP version to 7.3.9 (I cannot choose 7.3.7). The issue is still there.

Comment: may be, but some thing wrong with your ssl config too i think

Comment: You can force all connections to your DB instance to use SSL. If you force connections to use SSL, it happens transparently to the client, and the client doesn't have to do any work to use SSL.

If you want to force SSL, use the rds.force_ssl parameter. By default, the rds.force_ssl parameter is set to false. Set the rds.force_ssl parameter to true to force connections to use SSL. The rds.force_ssl parameter is static, so after you change the value, you must reboot your DB instance for the change to take effect.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/SQLServer.Concepts.General.SSL.Using.html

Comment: @Adiii The article you linked is only valid for "Microsoft SQL Server" instances. My instance is running "Aurora" and there is no rds.force_ssl parameter in the parameter group for my instance.

Comment: yeah got it, let try to debug without SSL config just to verify is it accessible or not

Comment: Without using SSL it works fine. It even works when I'm using the SSL config but try to connect using credentials of a user that does not require SSL.

Comment: so one thing is clear that it works without SSL?

Comment: how you create MySQL user? how you set the password?

Comment: Yes, absolutely sure. I just checked the `phpinfo()` on the shared hosting. It says MySQL Client API Version: 5.5.52. I seems like Amazon RDS supports TLS starting with MySQL 5.7, but I'm not really sure if this means server or client version.

Comment: which version of mysql RDS you are using?

Comment: I added the user like so: `CREATE USER 'username'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';` And then I did: `GRANT DELETE, DROP, EXECUTE, INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE, ALTER ROUTINE, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ON db_name.* TO 'username'@'%' REQUIRE SSL;`

Comment: ` with RDS MySQL 5.6, older versions of MariaDB 10.0 and 10.1, and Aurora MySQL 5.6 only supporting TLS 1.0. `

Comment: I'm using Amazon Aurora MySQL, Engine version 5.6.10a.

Comment: so check the TLS version on which against you are trying to connect

Comment: I don't really know how to do this.

Comment: when you place the ssl config, read its properties or you can read in the documentation of shared hosting provider

Comment: First another thing: In my script above there was a typo. I wrote `value` instead of `Value`. Now when running locally I get the expected output: `Does the ca file exist? true
Connected to database.
DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA`

Comment: Now the other thing: I hope I'm doing what you mean here. I did a query `SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Ssl_Version'` and when running locally I get `TLSv1` as value, but when running on shared hosting I get an empty string (when connecting with the user that does not require SSL).

Comment: so if that does not require ssl so it mean you are not enforcing ssl?

Comment: That's basically the problem: When I'm trying to connect to the user that **requires** SSL I get the `Access denied` error. But this happens **only** when using the shared hosting. Enforcing SSL works when I'm running the script locally.

Comment: I just ran another test using an Amazon EC2 instance. I uploaded the exact same file and I could connect from there. So it works from my home and from the EC2 instance, but not from the Strato shared hosting server. Any idea what configuration on their end could cause this? I think I'll also contact them.

Comment: YEs please do connect with support team

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199798/discussion-on-question-by-coder2k-access-denied-when-trying-to-connect-to-amaz).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Adiii and @benra I found the cause of the problem: Since PHP 5.3.0 it normally uses the [MySQL Native Driver](https://www.php.net/manual/de/book.mysqlnd.php), but the shared hoster I use (Strato) has a PHP 7 installation that still uses the legacy MySQL driver. Therefore `MYSQLI_OPT_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT` (for mysqli) and `MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT` (for pdo) are not available, which causes the problem when using CA-files of cloud providers like Amazon RDS or Google Cloud.
My solution to this will be to use an own V-Server.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a lot like a security group problem. When you are testing locally you are probably entering the RDS with your private IP over a certain port (if SSL 443).

Probably you don't have the security group configured, that the inbound traffic is allowed from other public IPs.
I would double check all the security group rules. If it allows your local connections and what you allow if it is another IP.

Comment: For testing purposes at the moment there's no specific IP set. To be exact: My inbound rules are `MYSQL/Aurora (Protocol TCP, Port 3306), Source 0.0.0.0/0` and `(MYSQL/Aurora (Procotol TCP, Port 3306), Source ::/0`. My (only) outbound rule is `All traffic (Protocol All, Port Range All), Destination 0.0.0.0/0`. Also I think MySQL with SSL uses Port 3306 and not 443. But either way: If it works from my home PC (and another V-Server), it should also work from the shared hosted webspace, right?